# Need help on creating Custom Pivot chart

Tags: excel, charts, pivot

I need help in creating a Pivot chart. I have dates as a timeline and 4 categories but the values are difference between those 4 categories with points and without points.

I want a pivot chart with 4 categories as a column on each month and out of those 4 column it is stack with the value of categories without and with points

I tried creating it on pivot chart combo but it won't work and also trying to overlap two pivot chart but its ugly

The output in mind is something like this. A stack column within stack pivot chart. So example below is a column chart I need to change the value representation on each column chart that it has stack of those 4 categories with and without points

[image: stack column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot charts are very limited compared to the charting techniques that can be used in regular charts.  You can build a regular chart based on the data that the pivot table returns. If the number of rows of the pivot table varies, you can use dynamic range names with formulas that capture the pivot table columns and use these for the chart.

What you describe looks very much like a stacked clustered column chart, which is not a standard chart, but can be created with a few tricks. Jon Peltier has a tutorial [here](https://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/) for a result that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Such a stacked bar chart out of a pivot table can be created with https://www.koia.io.

The source code is on https://github.com/centeractive/koia

Koia protects your data privacy -  you do NOT need to upload your data but it ALWAYS stays local on your machine.

In koia, you can create pivots with just a couple of mouseclicks:

- Choose the data that you want to work with
- Go to the pivot table tab in the header
- Drag&drop your columns/row values as you want them to be displayed in your pivot table
- Choose the “stacked bar chart” option in the upper right corner (see picture)

Koia will automatically create the stacked bar chart.

The drag&drop options allow you to play around with your data (timeline and different categories) and see the changes in real-time
[image]